# Squashing values in a column by another timestamp colum

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a following data which shows the status of a support ticket:

---

#### Edit:

More concise and generic example:

```
STATUS        SEQ_NO
New           1
Open          2
Open          3
Open          4
Queued        5
Open          6
Open          7
Open          8
Completed     9
Completed     10
Completed     11
Closed        12
```

From this, I would like to extract the records,

```
STATUS        SEQ_NO
New           1
Open          2
Queued        5
Open          6
Completed     9
Closed        12
```

---

#### Original question:

```
-- SELECT status, start_time FROM events_tab ORDER BY start_time;
STATUS        START_TIME
New           30/09/2014 3:48:10 PM    -- I want this record,
Open          30/09/2014 3:48:10 PM    -- and this,
Open          1/10/2014 10:41:57 AM
Open          4/03/2015 9:59:04 AM
Queued        18/06/2015 1:31:30 PM    -- and this,
Open          20/06/2015 10:10:47 PM   -- and this,
Open          20/06/2015 11:20:11 PM
Open          27/06/2015 1:18:50 PM
Completed     27/06/2015 1:22:08 PM    -- and this,
Completed     28/09/2015 9:31:55 AM
Completed     5/10/2015 11:57:38 AM
Closed        11/01/2016 9:31:26 AM    -- and this.
```

These are events that happened in each state. I want to make a timeline of state changes from it.

I want to squash these records such that only the very first row of a group is show. However, notice that there are actually two groups of `Open` status. So I should get two records with `Open` status.

Basically I want the following result:

```
STATUS        START_TIME
New           30/09/2014 3:48:10 PM
Open          30/09/2014 3:48:10 PM
Queued        18/06/2015 1:31:30 PM
Open          20/06/2015 10:10:47 PM
Completed     27/06/2015 1:22:08 PM
Closed        11/01/2016 9:31:26 AM
```

How can I achieve this with an SQL statement?

I have tried,

```
SELECT status, MIN(start_time)
FROM events_tab
GROUP BY status;
```

But this does not include multiple records in `Open` status, as my intention above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Tabibitosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2014/01/tabibitosan.html) technique to achieve this goal:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 'New' status, to_date('30/09/2014 03:48:10 PM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') start_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Open' status, to_date('30/09/2014 03:48:10 PM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') start_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Open' status, to_date('1/10/2014 10:41:57 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') start_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Open' status, to_date('4/03/2015 09:59:04 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') start_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Queued' status, to_date('18/06/2015 01:31:30 PM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') start_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Open' status, to_date('20/06/2015 10:10:47 PM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') start_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Open' status, to_date('20/06/2015 11:20:11 PM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') start_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Open' status, to_date('27/06/2015 01:18:50 PM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') start_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Completed' status, to_date('27/06/2015 01:22:08 PM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') start_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Completed' status, to_date('28/09/2015 09:31:55 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') start_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Completed' status, to_date('5/10/2015 11:57:38 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') start_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Closed' status, to_date('11/01/2016 09:31:26 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') start_time FROM dual)
SELECT status,
       MIN(start_time) start_time
FROM   (SELECT status,
               start_time,
               row_number() OVER (ORDER BY start_time, status) - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY status ORDER BY start_time, status) grp
        FROM   your_table)
GROUP BY status, grp
ORDER BY start_time, status;

STATUS    START_TIME
--------- -------------------
New       30/09/2014 15:48:10
Open      30/09/2014 15:48:10
Queued    18/06/2015 13:31:30
Open      20/06/2015 22:10:47
Completed 27/06/2015 13:22:08
Closed    11/01/2016 09:31:26
```

N.B. Since you have rows with different statuses having the same start_time, I have added status into the order by, in order to get the results you were after. I don't know if that was a typo, or whether multiple rows really can have the same date.

Also, I assume that the data in your example refers to one "thing", but in your real table, you can have multiple "things" each with their own set of statuses etc.

In that case, you would need to add the column(s) that differentiate the "things" (e.g. id or event_name or etc) into both `row_number()` analytic functions. (e.g. `row_number() over (partition by <thing column(s)> order by start_time, status)`)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the [SQL for Pattern Matching](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm#DWHSG8956)

```
WITH tickets(STATUS, START_TIME) AS (
    SELECT 'New', TO_DATE('30/09/2014 3:48:10 PM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Open', TO_DATE('30/09/2014 3:48:10 PM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Open', TO_DATE('1/10/2014 10:41:57 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Open', TO_DATE('4/03/2015 9:59:04 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Queued', TO_DATE('18/06/2015 1:31:30 PM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Open', TO_DATE('20/06/2015 10:10:47 PM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Open', TO_DATE('20/06/2015 11:20:11 PM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Open', TO_DATE('27/06/2015 1:18:50 PM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Completed', TO_DATE('27/06/2015 1:22:08 PM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Completed', TO_DATE('28/09/2015 9:31:55 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Completed', TO_DATE('5/10/2015 11:57:38 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Closed', TO_DATE('11/01/2016 9:31:26 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') FROM dual)
SELECT STATUS, START_TIME
FROM tickets
    MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
        ORDER BY START_TIME
        MEASURES
            START_TIME AS START_TIME,
            STATUS as STATUS
        PATTERN ( CHNG )
        DEFINE
            CHNG AS CHNG.STATUS <> PREV(CHNG.STATUS) OR PREV(CHNG.STATUS) IS NULL
    )


STATUS     START_TIME
========== ====================
New        30.09.2014 15:48:10
Open       30.09.2014 15:48:10
Queued     18.06.2015 13:31:30
Open       20.06.2015 22:10:47
Completed  27.06.2015 13:22:08
Closed     11.01.2016 09:31:26
```

`CHNG.STATUS <> PREV(CHNG.STATUS)` matches each row where `STATUS` is different to previous row. `PREV(CHNG.STATUS) IS NULL` is used to get also the very first row.

Answer (score 0):

Use LAG Function as you need to track the change in status:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=38a991b698c858f6f0417c7d4c0dc9d3

```
with cte1 (st,dt) as 
(
select 'New' as st, '30/09/2014 3:48:10 PM' as dt from dual
union all
select 'Open' as st, '30/09/2014 3:48:10 PM' as dt from dual
union all
select 'Open' as st, '20/09/2014 3:48:10 PM' as dt from dual
union all
select 'Qued' as st, '18/06/2015 1:31:30' as dt from dual

)
select st, min(case when st<>prev_order_date then dt else dt end) as d
from
(
SELECT st, dt,
LAG (st,1) OVER (ORDER BY st) AS prev_order_date
FROM cte1
)a
group by st
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wouldn't that select two records from the first `Open` group? There are records for 2014 and 2015 in there.

Comment: yes, but it will select min start time for 2014 by status, and 2015 by status, only one confusion from your data point is Open          4/03/2015 9:59:04 AM - why you exclude this from your expected output? - is there any logic

Comment: Yes, these are events that happened in each state. I want to make a timeline of state changes from it.

Comment: modified the answer with demo , you can check now @Krumia

Comment: Unfortunately this hardcodes the values. I want a dynamic way to filter the very first row of each group.

Comment: it's not hardcoded value, its a example from your sample data, if you are execute in your table it will be resulted in dynamic way, with cte is just a construction of a dummy table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180414/discussion-between-fa06-and-krumia).

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number` window function

```
    select STATUS ,START_TIME from 
    (
    select STATUS,START_TIME,
    row_number() over (partition by STATUS,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM START_TIME) order by START_TIME) rn
   from events_tab
    ) t where rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a bit confused, where does `event_tab` (the table name) go in this?

Comment: Thanks I think this work. I'll test with some other data and accept your answer in a little while.

Comment: Unfortunately this actually gives the wrong result. Instead of `Open 20/06/2015`, it gives me `Open 4/03/2015`.